# Drag and Drop, Orderable List in ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, components, flash-cs4, flash-v3-components

I am trying to create a set of drag-and-drop, orderable lists with ActionScript. I know this is possible in Flex.

The behavior I am going for can be seen here: [Two-way drag-and drop support](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/adding_drag_and_drop/#list) (you'll have to scroll down)

Here is the [source code](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/adding_drag_and_drop/src/DragAndDropSimpleTwoWay/index.html)

Does something like this already exist in AS? Can I use the Flex component in Flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/as3-drag-and-drop-tilelist/) seems to be close enough. ^_^